# Org mode: exporting new customized emphasis markers

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-emphasis

In my emacs org mode, I created a new customized emphasis marker (added to Org Emphasis Alist) with the caracter "¡" associated with the font-lock-face "hi-pink" (I use the solarized theme).

This works fine to highlight text displayed within emacs.

But when I try to export my org file into a latex or a html file, I get an error message: "unknown marker". It seems that the new marker is not recognized for exporting.

Is there a way to get the new emphasis marker exported to html, latex or other backend formats (lets say, as a source code text)?

If not, is it possible at least to tell org mode to ignore the new customized emphasis mark, in order to accomplish the export process?

Thanks in advance for your help!
(congratulations for this website!!)